# Making Wind Tunnel

Tags: volumetrics, collision, force-fields

i just need a wind effector, which is limited in the width. It has a setting for min and max Distance, but i want to control the width so that i have a specific wind tunnel. Is that somehow possible?

I made a simple scene where you have a Cyclinder with a wind Force Field in it. If you bake it instead of that the wind blows the smoke only on this area up it blows the whole smoke up if it´s activated. (Wind is parented to Cylinder)

My goal is to control the smoke so that it goes to the two sides and then up as in the picture and does not spread out in a circle.

[image]

[Testfile](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qia6x7khQfJdcoEErsDpkSw_lCEKMKfV/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: you should tell us your "end goal". For me - i don't get what you want and maybe a sketch would help. You can model a tunnel as you want - so this could be your wind effector. Then put a force field wind in the tunnel and add collision to tunnel....this is what i understood what you want. But i am pretty sure....you will now comment "nah, that's not what i want" so pls improve your question

Comment: Oh yes that´s exactly what i want :D I'm doing a rocket launch and I want the smoke from the engines to be blown down quickly in the middle and out again to the side. If I only use normal wind, everything is pushed down.

Comment: Ok too bad but it doesn´t work. The wind isn´t effected by the tunnel add with activated Fluid Effector Collisions. Also not if i set the collision object to Planar :(

Comment: pls add blend file so we can check it out. thx

Comment: Hello, now i made a simple scene where you can test it. Thanks!

Comment: you wouldn't do it with an effector...you would work with high initial velocity

Comment: But the high initial velocity is going down and to the side it has to go up?

Comment: In your picture it goes up only on the side - that’s what hoch velocity will do as well

Comment: But it first have to go down. So you mean an extra velocity?

Comment: if you want an explicit animation, you should insert a link to your question to make it crystal clear what you want. You just inserted one picture so it is not clear how the animation should look like....